# Trying to provide some simple command line interfaces

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to provide command line user interface for the script by using by using ArgumentParser
from the library argparse. It is not supposed to be any advanced argument parser, just a couple ones specifying the input- and output image filename by/with help flags. I have read quite a lot about how to do it, but find it difficult. The code underneath shows what I have done so far. Any suggestions on how to make it better so it might work?

```
# Import the argparse library
import argparse

# Construct the argument parser and parse the argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Specify the input- and output file")
parser.add_argument("box_kernel", help = "The type of kernel")
parser.add_argument("input_image", help = "The input file(image)")
parser.add_argument("output_image", help = "Creating the output image")

args = parser.parse_args()


# Oppgave 4.1

import timeit
import numpy 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw # Importerer biblioteket
start = timeit.default_timer()


# Load image:
input_image = Image.open("beatles.jpg") 
input_pixels = input_image.load()

# Box Blur kernel
box_kernel = [[1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9]]

# Select kernel here:
kernel = box_kernel(args["box_kernel"])

# Middle of the kernel
offset = len(kernel) // 2

# Creating the output image
output_image = Image.new("RGB", input_image.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)


# Beregne konvolusjon mellom intensity (original bilde) og  kernel 
for x in range(offset, input_image.width - offset):
    for y in range(offset, input_image.height - offset):
        acc = [0, 0, 0]
        for a in range(len(kernel)):
            for b in range(len(kernel)):
                xn = x + a - offset
                yn = y + b - offset
                pixel = input_pixels[xn, yn]
                acc[0] += pixel[0] * kernel[a][b]
                acc[1] += pixel[1] * kernel[a][b]
                acc[2] += pixel[2] * kernel[a][b]

draw.point((x, y), (int(acc[0]), int(acc[1]), int(acc[2])))

output_image.save("Beatles box blur.png")

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Comment: what do you mean "so it might work"?  what do you consider wrong with the code you posted, and what do you want it to do?  you also might consider using `opencv` as it has code for doing 2d convolutions much faster than your nested loops

Comment: @SamMason The code is working without the command lines, but I am trying to attach some command lines. The task is: Provide a command line user interface for your script using ArgumentParser
from the library argparse. The design should provide instructions by calling it with a --help flag, and it should be possible to specify the input and output image filename. The nestled loops are used since it was a part of the task :)

Comment: I'm not doing your homework!  though I will help you learn, and all my questions from above still stand.  what's wrong with it, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: I understand that :) So basically I want/trying to make two command line arguments which gives the following information: 1: CLI to view the input filename of the code, 2: CLI to view the output filename of the code.

Comment: then I'd suggest editing the question to include some examples, e.g. some cases that should succeed, some that should fail, and what should happen in those cases

Comment: I understand. I will try to do that!

Comment: What errors do you get, if any?  During debugging add a `print(args)` line.  That way you'll see what the parser does.  It that's ok, then the problems are later.  `args` is a `Namespace` object  Use `kernel=args.box_kernel` to access that attribute.  Use `args.input_image` etc to open the desired file.